# Pasting formatted text from HTML into MS Access memo form field

Tags: ms-access

I have a super simple MS Access form with two fields to collect some data quickly, one of which is a memo data type, wired into a table field.  I want to copy some formatted text from HTML into it and would like to preserve the formatting (bolding, fonts, italic, etc.).  However, when I do `Ctrl-C` --> `Ctrl-V`, it only pastes unformatted plain text.

Is there any way I can configure my form field to accept and save formatted text?  If I paste the same into MS Word, the formatting IS preserved.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to open the 'source' of the HTML file, and only then copy+paste.

From the browser, you'll just see the HTML output.. and some apps, like Notepad, won't be able to store the data through a simple copy+paste. MS Word can do it, as you might already know, since it is a rich-text editor.

As for a field in MS Access, you can only preserve the formatting if you copy the source itself. It will help if you let us know which browser you are copying from, though normally, there is an option to view the source code of the page being viewed.

[edit:in response to comment]
If you want rich text to enter into an ms access field, try the first few steps here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/insert-or-add-a-rich-text-field-HA010014097.aspx

Comment: but i don't want to paste the HTML -- i want to paste what the browser displays

Comment: Hmmm, if you mean to have a rich text column, then may I suggest my edited/added answer above?